# Windows Phone Tile Notification - URI for image stored in Shared/ShellContent

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, isolatedstorage, mpns

I have an application which leverages push notification. When the application receives tile notifications with the background image pointing to images bundled as resources with the xap, the images are nicely loaded on the pinned tile. Furthermore, i tested with the app running the possibility of loading an image on the pinned tile with the file stored in isolated storage at Shared/ShellContent and that works too. The URI schema i used this is 'isostore:' However, when i try to give that URI or any other combinations of it in the XML of my Tile Notification, i am unable to load the referred images.

I checked the docs in MSDN but to no avail. Would someone know if it is at all possible? Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Windows-Phone-7-Push-Notification-QuickApp--Web-Service-With-Azure-Publishing-Instructions). You may want to add your domain name to the list of allowed domains. Here is the code snippet from the tutorial's soruce code.

```
var ListOfAllowedDomains = new Collection<Uri> {
    // Lists domains that can send tile updates and so forth as push notifications. 
    // Only these authorized domains will be allowed by the shell to push new tiles to the phone
    new Uri(@"http://YOUR WEB SERVICE'S DOMAIN HERE") // e.g. if you published a webservice at http://foo.com/service1.svc -- put "http://foo.com" here.
};

//Register this channel with the shell, pass on authorized domain in way method expects
myPushChannel.BindToShellTile(ListOfAllowedDomains);
```

I have fully integrated this into one of my mobile Apps and it is working smoothly. If I understand your question correctly, you want to pull these Images through a relative URI which is hosted in the service.

Comment: First thanks for the reply :) Sadly, i think that i did not explain the point well. In short i do not want to access a resource that is hosted in the web. Rather, i would like to access something stored in the isolated storage. More explicitly, i would like to construct the Tile Notification XML data so that the background image parameter points correctly to an image stored in the Isolated Storage. I am able to change the image on a tile via the "ISOSTORE:" scheme but only from code and not from Tile Notification. So, would you know the URI scheme to do that in case it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use local resource or remote resource only to update background image of a tile, and it's not possible to use isolated storage.

From MSDN:

> Background image. You can use a local resource or remote resource for
>   the background image of a Tile. If you want to use a local resource,
>   it must have been installed as a part of the XAP package. For example,
>   it is not possible to download an image, put it into isolated storage,
>   and then use it as a local resource for the background image of the
>   Tile.

Comment: Would be nice if you can give the link to the MSDN page you quoted.